# Access token_unidentified

Tags: reactjs, authentication, token, storage, local

I  am building a Token authentication in **React** and have an issue. Below there are two lines of  the code:
when I use proper code according to eslint:

```
const { token } = response.data.token;
```

it returns no error, but I cannot see the  `access_token`, it is unidentified in local storage

when I use not proper code according to eslint:

```
const token=response.data.token;
```

then it shows me the actual code in local storage.

What is happening?

Comment: Correct syntax would be `const { token } = response.data;`

Answer (score 1):

`const { token } = response.data.token;` is sugar for `const token = response.data.token.token;`, which is not what you want.

The following will be equivalent to your second snippet:

```
const { token } = response.data;
```